# Can gtag.js be configured to send GA4 event data to two different GA4 Measurement IDs?

Tags: google-tag-manager, gtag.js

We would like to send GA4 event data to 2 different GA4 Measurement Ids.  Can gtag.js be configured to do this?

We know this can be configured for UA and GA4, but what about two or possibly more GA4 Measurement Ids?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can set up the gtag like thie

[image]

```
<!-- Google tag (gtag.js) -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-111111111"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'G-111111111');
  gtag('config', 'G-222222222');
  gtag('config', 'G-333333333');
</script>
```

---

Then when you fire event:

[image]

```
<script>
  gtag('event', 'test', {
    'test_p1': 'test_v1'
  });
</script>
```

You will send the ga4 event hits to all the config measurement in gtag.

[image]

But if you have more complicated requirements like

1. Event A to all config
2. Event B to some of the config

Please take a look at the [document](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/gtagjs/routing)